# Spring Batch Job Infinite Loop

Tags: spring-batch

I have found an strange issue with Java Spring Batch during the last minute of Production Release. It goes into infinite loop.

Here is the config of mine:

```
<batch:job id="dbasJob" restartable="true">       
    <batch:step id="dbasStep" next="webService">         
        <tasklet>             
            <chunk reader="campaignReader" processor="campaignProcessor" writer="campaignWriter" commit-interval="1" 
                skip-limit="50">

                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>

                <listeners>
                    <listener ref="campaignProcessListener" />
                    <listener ref="campaignSkipListener" />
                </listeners>
            </chunk>         
        </tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="promotionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>     
    </batch:step>
```

Total Number of records is 10. So the Commit happens after every single record is processed.
I'm writing the results into database in the Writer.

I'm fetching items one by one from the Reader, processing and writing to DB.

```
public Campaign read()
{   
    return campaignList.isEmpty() ? null : campaignList.remove(0);
}

public Campaign process(Campaign campaign) throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {

    try 

public void write(List<? extends Campaign> campaignList) throws Exception 
{//...Writing to DB...
```

It keeps running and inserting data into the table infinitely.

Observation is: Commit-Interval < TotalRecords and Skip-Limit > Commit-Interval.

If someone suggest some solution/workaround, would of greatest help to me at the point of time where Production release is held because of this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1794) about this problem

Comment: While there is an issue open for it, you'll notice that we haven't been able to reproduce this behavior.  If you could contribute a test case that does, it would help a lot with our efforts to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen that open ticket for this infinite loop issue, but actually that was not the cause in my case, even though Skip limit is larger than commit limit. I was filling the list back with data in the writer. that was the reason it was going into infinite loop as the list will never get exhausted. Now i have resolved the issue. But still not sure about this ticket. Thanks.